# forms authentication in Subdomain override authentication in Main domain

Tags: asp.net, forms, authentication

I am a fresher in ASP.NET. I have one issue about the forms authentication, I have a web application(HPE) with forms authentication, which is already deployed into IIS,

There is a Eligibility web site in the web server,which is developed in classic ASP, it uses forms authentication. That main web site has link to web applications such as HPE,CHDP,BCCDP etc. When i click a HPE link, I would redirect to HPE application, i set the HPE ticket timeout to be 20 minutes(the same with main site).

When i stay in the HPE for over 20 minutes (doing something to keep HPE ticket valid), i click side bar CHDP link (which points to CHDP application), it would directly goes to timeout page instead of CHDP app. Are there any ways that i can go to other pages in main site while i stay in HPE application for 20 minites?

Below is the authentication part for HPE in web.config

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name=".HPEAUTH" loginUrl="Logout.aspx?go=login" timeout="20" defaultUrl="/Eligibility/Cookiemonster.asp" requireSSL="false" protection="All" path="/" slidingExpiration="true"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Sorry that i didn't find any web.config file in the Eligibility(main site) directory. Any idea or though would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To use the same authentication cookie across multiple applications, you will have to ensure that the `machineKey` section of your `web.config` file is set to the same thing on all apps.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> The following example shows the Authentication section of a Web.config
>   file. Unless otherwise noted, the name, protection, path,
>   validationKey, validation, decryptionKey, and decryption attributes
>   must be identical across all applications. Similarly, the encryption
>   and validation key values and the encryption scheme and validation
>   scheme used for authentication tickets (cookie data) must be the same.
>   If the settings do not match, authentication tickets cannot be shared.
>   For information about how to generate values for the validationKey and
>   decryptionKey attributes, see How To: Configure MachineKey in ASP.NET
>   2.0. (This topic applies to ASP.NET version 2.0 and to later versions.)

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <!-- The name, protection, and path attributes must match 
           exactly in each Web.config file. -->
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx"
        name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" 
        protection="All"  
        path="/" 
        domain="contoso.com" 
        timeout="30" />
    </authentication>

    <!-- Validation and decryption keys must exactly match and cannot
         be set to "AutoGenerate". The validation and decryption
         algorithms must also be the same. -->
    <machineKey
      validationKey="C50B3C89CB21F4F1422FF158A5B42D0E8DB8CB5CDA1742572A487D9401E3400267682B202B746511891C1BAF47F8D25C07F6C39A104696DB51F17C529AD3CABE" 
      decryptionKey="8A9BE8FD67AF6979E7D20198CFEA50DD3D3799C77AF2B72F" 
      validation="SHA1" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```